# Server Side Rendering of Dynamic URL using NUXT 3

Tags: dynamic, nuxt.js, rendering, server-side-rendering, static-site-generation

I am using NUXT3 for one of my project. I am able to nuxt generate the dist folder for SSG. Now I am having dynamic url for my project. That is /page/resources/[post].vue , Based on the passed route parameter I want to call an API and bond the response to the template before rendering it to the client. So that on giving view page source I get my page with the data. I need this for SEO purpose. Please help me with the configurations and setup that has my previous pages along with this dynamic routes being SSR.

I am open to all the possible choices.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.